# Check python string format?

Tags: python, string, data-manipulation

I have a bunch of strings but I only want to keep the ones with this format:

x/x/xxxx xx:xx

What is the easiest way to check if a string meets this format? (Assuming I want to check by if it has 2 /'s and a ':' )

Comment: The simplest way is to convert it into a datetime and catch the error when it fails. It is a datetime right?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

try with regular expresion:

```
import re
r = re.compile('.*/.*/.*:.*')
if r.match('x/x/xxxx xx:xx') is not None:
   print 'matches'
```

you can tweak the expression to match your needs

Comment: Thing is, stuff like `'xxxxx/xxxxx/x 124453:24345'` also matches that. Use: `././.{4} .{2}:.{2}`, assuming it's any character. If it has to be digits: `\d/\d/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}`

Comment: right, but the original post says: Assuming I want to check by if it has 2 /'s and a ':'. The example looks like a date format, but is it a date?

Comment: He also gave a format he wanted to keep before, which looks exactly like a datetime format - I'd assume it was needed to be exact to that format personally.

Answer (score 10):

Use [time.strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) to parse from string to time struct. If the string doesn't match the format it raises `ValueError`.

Answer (score 8):

If you use regular expressions with match you must also account for the end being too long.  Without testing the length in this code it is possible to slip any non-newline character at the end.  Here is code modified from other answers.

```
import re
r = re.compile('././.{4} .{2}:.{2}')
s = 'x/x/xxxx xx:xx'
if len(s) == 14:
  if r.match(s):
    print 'matches'
```