# check GPS string format

Tags: python, string

I have some GPS coordinate data e.g.

```
38 41'13.2"N
96 30'23.4"E
```

How can I check it has a constant format? Sometimes the data is like:

```
38 41.2342
96 30.1211
```

I tried using re, but the punction inside the string makes it difficult to pass through.

Ideal format is XX XX'XX.X"(E or N)

I tried

```
import re
r = re.compile(".* .*'.*..*"N")
if r.match('48 46'55.3"N') is not None:
   print 'matches'
```

taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966647/check-python-string-format)

Comment: Punctuation should not be a problem. What did you try?

Comment: This will work: `[NE]$`. If not, more details please.

Comment: What exactly is the "correct" format? Do you expect values to be zero-padded? How many decimal places do you accept, and where?  Are integers required to have zero'd decimal places? What values are acceptable for the cardinal direction at the end (`S`, `SW`, `SSW`, etc...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't escaped your quotes in your example. Notice the `\"` on line 2, and the `\'` on line 3. This is important so that python knows the quote is part of the string, and not terminating it.

I have also used a slightly more explicit pattern.

```
import re
r = re.compile("^\d{2} \d{2}'\d{2}.\d{1}\"[EN]$")
if r.match('48 46\'55.3"N') is not None:
    print 'matches'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your punctuation problems are (1) you need to escape the `.` with a backslash when you want to match the actual decimal point, otherwise it matches any character; and (2) you need to escape the double-quote or otherwise prevent it from terminating your string.

The best way to write this as a readable debuggable regex is to use a Python "raw" string `r"like this"` which allows backslashes without escaping, and furthermore to triple-quote it, which lets you to use both `'` and `"` inside it without escaping.  And since triple-quoted strings allow multi-line expressions, you could even compile in `VERBOSE` mode, allowing whitespace and comments.  Debuggability of your subsequent matching/extraction code is also improved if you use the `(?P<...>)` named-group syntax in your regex—groups will then be accessible by meaningful names, in the match object's `groupdict()` output.  Taken all together, that gives us:

```
PATTERNS = [ # a list of alternative acceptable formats

    re.compile( r"""              
        ^\s*                      # beginning of string (optional whitespace)
        (?P<degrees>\d+)[\s]      # integer number of degrees (NB: might be desirable to insert the degree symbol into the square brackets here, to allow that as a possibility?)
        (?P<minutes>\d+)'         # integer number of minutes
        (?P<seconds>\d+(\.\d*)?)" # seconds, with optional decimal point and decimal places
        (?P<axis>[NE]?)           # optional 'N' or 'E' character (remove '?' to make it compulsory)
        \s*$                      # end of string (optional whitespace)
    """, re.VERBOSE ),            

    re.compile( r"""
        ^\s*                      # beginning of string (optional whitespace)
        (?P<degrees>\d+)[\s]      # integer number of degrees (NB: might be desirable to insert the degree symbol into the square brackets here, to allow that as a possibility?)
        (?P<minutes>\d+(\.\d*)?)  # minutes, with optional decimal point and decimal places
        (?P<axis>[NE]?)           # optional 'N' or 'E' character (remove this line if this is never appropriate in this format)
        \s*$                      # end of string (optional whitespace)
    """, re.VERBOSE ),            

]
```