# String in specific format

Tags: python

how can I check in python if string is in correct format?
I have variable **tag**, and it should be in fomrat **0.0**

e.g

```py
tag = "1.0"

if tag != (is not in format **0.0**):
    print("not in tag")"
else:
    print("correct tag")"
```

In bash it looks like this

```sh
tag="10.0"
if [[ $tag != "${tag%.*}.${tag#*.}" ]]; then
    echo "wrong tag"
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest implementation is to use regular expressions:

```
if not re.search("^\d+\.\d+$", tag):
    #does not match
```

Answer (score 1):

As referenced from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966647/check-python-string-format), I would recommend looking into regular expressions.

Ex:

```
import re
r = re.compile("^(\d*\.)?\d+$")
if r.match(tag) is not None:
   print('match')
else:
   print('not match')
```